# Any possible online repository

Tags: git, tortoisesvn, tortoisegit

Hi I would like to ask if there is any application or online site that I could use to put my project source codes wherein I could share the code and let my friends checkout the codes and commit their changes?

I apologise to my question, I am not sure where I could ask this so I am trying my luck here. Hope you understand.

Thank you. Appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Erm, GitHub? Bitbucket?

Comment: You’re describing GitHub

Comment: geeeeethubbabubbaa! ...... sorry, I got exited, I mean I concur, its github (create an account on github.com)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [github.com](http://github.com)
- [gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com/explore)
- [bitbucket.org](http://bitbucket.org)
- ...

Comment: hi i am trying GitHub however I really dont have idea how to use this, I am stuck after creating repository, maybe you could help me with it?

Comment: GitHub should display a howto while your repository is empty. Or take a look at https://help.github.com/categories/bootcamp/. If you're new to git: https://git-scm.com/doc, https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2, https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial, https://git-scm.com/documentation/external-links

Comment: Just create an account. Login. Then select the "+" sign in the top right and click create new repository. Fill in the repo info (some very simple parameters like its name) and then click create (can't quite recall which button). Once you have your repo you will see a URL like `https://github.com/<user-name>/<repo-name>.git`. Copy that and then enter `git clone https://github.com/<user-name>/<repo-name>.git` into a command prompt (or gitbash) and away you go....

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GitHub](http://github.com) or [Gitlab](http://gitlab.com) , even Bitbucket (I can't post a third link, sorry)

Comment: hi i am trying GitHub however I really dont have idea how to use this, I am stuck after creating repository, maybe you could help me with it?